# Data Population Scope in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

Could you help me: How can I change the Data Population Scope in DocuSign settings?
I tried to configure the text field data replication. But these settings only apply to fields with the same Data Label for a single file/document.
I found this article: [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/Why-is-Data-Replicating-in-Multiple-Fields-Using-Data-Population-Scope?language=en_US&rsc_301#:%7E:text=When%20you%20set%20multiple%20Data%20Labels%20to%20the,into%20all%20fields%20with%20the%20same%20Data%20Label)
I see here that it is possible to change the scope. But how???

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I used this video: [How To Replicate Text Fields Data in DocuSign Templates And Envelopes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1DhmtVhHlg). I see that it is possible to duplicate data both inside the page and inside the template. But I can use this function only with pages. How can I duplicate the data in the template scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to change the [Data Population Scope](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/Why-is-Data-Replicating-in-Multiple-Fields-Using-Data-Population-Scope?language=en_US&rsc_301) is to contact [DocuSign Customer Support](https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US&rsc_301). They can help you do this, there's no UI Settings to do that yourself.